# Node unable to find module alias defined in tsconfig and package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm trying to run a typescript project in production mode. [The code is here on Github](https://github.com/xameeramir/test-project)

- Running `npm run start:dev` is running the server up on http://localhost:3000/
- Running `npm run build` is generating the `dist` folder

The [`package.json`](https://github.com/xameeramir/test-project/blob/master/package.json) has the definition of `@server` defined using [module alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias):

```
"_moduleAliases": {
  "@server": "dist/Server"
}
```

The `@server` is defined under `compilerOptions.paths.@server` in [`tsconfig.json`](https://github.com/xameeramir/test-project/blob/master/tsconfig.json) too!

The [`index.ts`](https://github.com/xameeramir/test-project/blob/master/src/index.ts) imports `app` from `@server`;

```
import app from '@server';
```

When I run `npm start` - it does nothing

So I tried `node dist/index.js --env=production` and it throws the following error:

`Error: Cannot find module '@server'`

Why is the node not detecting this [module alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias)?

Comment: Post a minimal but complete set of code and configuration files to replicate the behavior instead of linking to the code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As stated on the [`module-alias` README](https://github.com/ilearnio/module-alias), it changes the default behavior of `require`. So, to use it, you have to add `require('module-alias/register')` to the beginning of your code before you import anything. I would suggest adding it to `LoadEnv.ts`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm testing this solution!